# Splitting results into 3 sections

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am creating a dashboard that has 3 tables each displaying a subset of the same data source.

[image]

Each table is supposed to hold the candidates deployed to a unique facility. Cycling through different facilities every 1 minute. I managed to get somewhat of a solution by using the below code:

```
DECLARE @tbl_Data TABLE ( CandName NVARCHAR(100), ReleaseDate DATE, FacilityNumber INT, FacilityName NVARCHAR(100), tblNum INT, RN INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl_Data ( CandName, ReleaseDate, FacilityNumber, FacilityName, tblNum)
SELECT 
    p.FullName AS CandName, 
    CAST(c.PlacementDate AS DATE) AS ReleaseDate,
    (SELECT TOP 1 IntegerValue FROM CustomAttributeValue WHERE CustomAttributeID = 24 AND ObjectID = cO.ID) AS [FacilityNumber],
    co.Name AS [FacilityName],
    NTILE(3) OVER ( ORDER BY p.Fullname DESC)
FROM contract c
LEFT JOIN Candidate cT ON c.CandidateId = ct.Id
LEFT JOIN Person p ON cT.Id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN Job j ON c.JobId = j.ID
LEFT JOIN Company cO ON j.CompanyId = cO.ID
WHERE LatestIssue = 1 AND ContractStartDate <= GETDATE() AND ContractEndDate > GETDATE() AND Conclusion = 0

;with UpdateData AS (
    SELECT CandName, ReleaseDate, FacilityNumber, FacilityName, tblNum, DENSE_Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY tblnum ORDER By FacilityName) RN
    FROM @tbl_Data
)
SELECT * FROm UpdateData ORDER BY tblNum
```

where `NTILE(3) OVER ( ORDER BY p.Fullname DESC)` splits the data into 3 sections and `DENSE_Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY tblnum ORDER By FacilityName) RN` gives me an ID to iterate through for each facility.

My problem is that the `NTILE` function often splits a single facility into different groups (tblnum). i.e. Having 6 candidates where 4 are placed in the same facility, the output would be:

```
Candidate       Facility       tblnum    RN
--------------------------------------------
John 1          Facility 1     1         1
John 2          Facility 1     1         1
John 3          Facility 1     2         1
John 4          Facility 1     2         1
John 5          Facility 2     3         1
John 6          Facility 2     3         1
```

The first 2 tables in the image would then be filled with 2 candidates from the same facility. What I want is the output to look like this:

```
Candidate       Facility       tblnum    RN
--------------------------------------------
John 1          Facility 1     1         1
John 2          Facility 1     1         1
John 3          Facility 1     1         1
John 4          Facility 1     1         1
John 5          Facility 2     2         1
John 6          Facility 2     2         1
```

Which would result in the 3rd table having no data. Im unsure whether this is best handled in Power BI or in SQL so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SQL has quite a few versatile functions to handle the kind of bucketing/binning you need, but the `NTILE()` function isn't a good fit for your requirements, namely that all rows for a given facility must land in the same bucket.

Instead of using `NTILE()` to split your result set into three bins, I recommend calling `DENSE_RANK()` in the main join query where it will sequentially number each unique facility in the result set, and then perform a `MOD 3` on that facility rank number to calculate its bin number (0, 1, or 2).

```
MOD( DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY co.Name ), 3 ) AS tblNum
```